# How to show function keys on Touchbar for NetBeans with MacBook?

Tags: netbeans, macbookpro-touch-bar

I have a Macbook with touch-bar. And I want my touch-bar always show function keys when I am working with NetBeans.
I've done with this link https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207240
But it doesn't work! (Off-course with Netbeans).

When I do that with Safari app, or other apps then fine!

I don't know why!

This is my Applications folder struct:

```
Applications
|
-----Safari.app
|
-----Netbeans
     |
     ------Netbeans.app
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this? I still have this issue.